# Where can I view all distros currently compliant with the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard?

Tags: linux, fhs

The Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard hasn't been updated since 2015. I'm assuming a lot has changed in the ecosystem since then, and because of this, certain distros may/may not be compliant with the standard anymore. I'm curious if there exists a list or some other store of information regarding the compliance status of various distros with the standard. Does anyone know?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#:~:text=The%20Filesystem%20Hierarchy%20Standard%20(FHS,released%20on%203%20June%202015. Just read the article, this isn't really an actual question, as that article says, it's a 'trailing' standard, which means it follows what distros actually do. Try googling before asking.

Comment: @Lizardx Maybe I'm not looking close enough but I don't see anywhere in that article (which I had already read prior to posting my question) a list of distros compliant with the standard. The article says that "Most Linux distributions follow the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and declare it their own policy to maintain FHS compliance", so I would think there would be someone/something keeping track of which distros declare their adherence.

Comment: No, you didn't read the article right. It's not a standard in the way you are thinking, that's why it's called a 'trailing sttandard'. It's not like being posix compliant or whatever. The article listed the 2 main ones that do not follow it, by design, and noted some variatoins that are starting up, like the use of /sbin is deprecated and is being dropped. This is what the 'trailing' means, as /sbin gets dropped, it will start to vanish, for example. Then they'll drop that one. There's no negative to dropping the stuff like that, it's just a change, nothing more.

Comment: What you need to know is not which follow it, but which don't, that's all that matters, and that's why that's what that article did, list the main two that are experimenting with a different system. To keep things working as deprecated directories are dropped, they add symbolic links so the paths remain. So the question is not which do it, but which don't. Nobody can track distros, they come and go, so the only thing you need to know is which are not doing it, they list NixOS and Gobolinux. /sys is not in the standard but is far more important than if /sbin is sym link to /usr/sbin or /usr/bin

Comment: Other examples of things rapidly becoming standard are /run instead of /var/run, sometimes /var/run links to /run, sometimes it doesn't and isnt' there, sometimes /var/run is there and /run isn't, it varies. But it's moving slowly towards /run, which if you look https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html you'll see isn't yet in the standard, but it is a standard if you make tools that need to look there for various temp type files. /sys is now there, but wasn't before, but /sys is evolving and getting more populated, so is now listed as a linux 'standard'.